# Dynamic Page Break on SSRS Report based on Parameter Selection

Tags: reporting-services

Currently SSRS Report is grouped by the following in the Row Group. When I export the report to excel it is broken into tabs by that ID. I am now passing a Parameter to the report that if set to false, the exported excel report should return only one tab. After doing a little research created an expression in the PageBreak Disabled Property. Whenever I run the report now no matter if I set the parameter to True or False it only returns a single tab. Can anyone offer any insight? THanks!

[image]

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

.Data File strikes again. Cleared cashe the expression worked.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted but a simpler way, without using any page breaks anywhere, is to set the `PageName` property in the row group properties to whatever your row group is grouping on or a static value based on your parameter  e.g. `= IIF (Parameters!myParm.Value=True, Fields!TheId.Value , "MyStaticTabName")`